# Doxygen, doxywizard encoding problem

Tags: character-encoding, doxygen, doxywizard

I work under Windows XP and I'm using **Doxygen** (actually **Doxywizard**) to create documentation.

I have a problem with encoding. In Doxywizard's bookmark `expert->proect->DOXYFILE_ENCODING` I wrote `cp1250` (I've tried also `Windows-1250`) but it still doesn't work and i do not get properly text.

I work in QtCreator.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you should use `INPUT_ENCODING` instead of `DOXYFILE_Encoding`. `DOXYFILE_ENCODING` is just the enconding for the config file and I guess you do not edit that manually since you are using the wizard.

Answer (score 1):

**Change the encoding exactly here**

[image]